# Inequality for concave function

Tags: real-analysis

Given $a'>a,b>0$ and $f$ concave, show that $f(a+b)-f(a)\geq f(a'+b)-f(a')$.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to show that inequality using the concave definition $f(tx+(1-t)y)\geq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$? Thank you!

Comment: @peter.petrov thanks for pointing that out, fixed that already

Comment: have you some others regularity on $f$?

Comment: @Soma In the context I have $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$. Do you think that is necessary for the statement?

Comment: Let me think some more, but I don't think you can prove this based on simply the fact that f is concave. Why would we be sure that $\Delta f(a) > \Delta f(a')$ for $\Delta x = b$? Or maybe it's true... hm...

Comment: @peter.petrov I guess it's because when we're on the increasing side of the function, then $a<a'$ means we'll have a higher $\Delta f(a)>\Delta f(a')$. When we're on the decreasing side of the function $\Delta f(a)<0$, but then $\Delta f(a')$ is even more negative.

Comment: It's true and it can be proved simply from the fact that $f$ is concave.

Comment: Seems I found that more direct approach I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general property of concavity is for $ x_1 < x_2 < x_3$

$$\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1} \geqslant \frac{f(x_3)-f(x_1)}{x_3-x_1} \geqslant \frac{f(x_3)-f(x_2)}{x_3- x_2}.$$

This can be proved from the basic $f(tx + (1-t)y) \geqslant tf(x) + (1-t)f(y)$ for $t \in [0,1]$.

With

$$t = \frac{x_3-x_2}{x_3 - x_1}$$

we have $x_2 = tx_1 + (1-t)x_3$ and

$$f(x_2) \geqslant \frac{x_3-x_2}{x_3 - x_1}f(x_1) +  \left[1-\frac{x_3-x_2}{x_3 - x_1}\right]f(x_3)\\ \implies \frac{f(x_3)-f(x_1)}{x_3-x_1} \geqslant \frac{f(x_3)-f(x_2)}{x_3- x_2}.$$

The other inequality is shown in a similar way using

$$t = \frac{x_2-x_1}{x_3 - x_1}.$$

Applying the three-slope inequality, if  $a < a' < a+b < a' +b$ then

$$\frac{f(a+b)-f(a)}{b} \geqslant \frac{f(a+b)-f(a')}{a+b-a'} \geqslant\frac{f(a'+b)-f(a')}{b}$$

In the other case, $a < a+b < a' <  a' +b$ and we have

$$\frac{f(a+b)-f(a)}{b} \geqslant \frac{f(a')-f(a+b)}{a'- a-b} \geqslant\frac{f(a'+b)-f(a')}{b}$$

Therefore,

$$f(a+b)-f(a) \geqslant f(a'+b) - f(a').$$

Comment: This is nice but ... Hm, the general property is pretty much what this problems asks us to prove. You just know it and use it :)

Comment: Oh, just added the proof of that property, then it would be OK.

Comment: No I just proved it -- see lines after "With $t = \frac{x_3-x_2}{x_3 - x_1}$ ...".

Comment: Right, right. OK... I will think if there's some more direct way. Nice problem.

Comment: This is the most basic way as far as I know since it uses the elementary definition of concavity.  I purposely put the solution in the framework of the more general three-slope inequality, because this is a very useful result which can be applied to many problems such as this.  Its worth knowing the general lemma.

Comment: Actually the lemma has perfect geometric meaning too. I see now, nice to know +1. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is that more direct approach which my intuition was telling me about.

It is based on the observation that the proportion in which $a+b$ divides the interval $[a, a'+b]$ is same as the proportion in which $a'$ divides the same interval (only viewed in the opposite direction). This also means that:

$\frac{(a+b) - a}{(a'+b-a)} + \frac{(a'-a)}{(a'+b-a)} = 1$.

That's because both points are at distance $b$ from one of the interval ends.

Now we don't need to look at different cases regarding which number is bigger, $a+b$ or $a'$.
What we know for sure is that they are both internal to that interval.

We can write (using the concavity property for the interval $[a, a'+b]$):

$f(a') \geqslant \frac{a'-a}{a'+b-a} \cdot f(a'+b) + \frac{b}{a'+b-a} \cdot f(a)$

(here we use $a'$ as the internal point, anyone can see what $t$ is)

Also (again using the concavity property for the interval $[a, a'+b]$):

$f(a+b) \geqslant \frac{b}{a'+b-a} \cdot f(a'+b) + \frac{a'-a}{a'+b-a} \cdot f(a)$

(here we use $a+b$ as the internal point, anyone can see what $t$ is)

Now we just add the two inequalities together and we get what we wanted to prove.

Comment: Looks good to me. +1